# JAVA - iterate through a folder of audio files, concatenating another audio file to each one

Tags: java, loops, audio

I am working on a small Java script to iterate through the .wav files in a folder named 'audiofiles', and concatenate each one individually with another audio file (named "silence_2sec.wav" in this case) So far I have:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class silapp_2b{

public static void main(String[]args){

String wavFile2 = "silence_2sec.wav";

            // get list of file names from audio directory

File audDir = new File("audiofiles");

       //define a list to contain the audio files names and path

 File[] filesList = audDir.listFiles();

       // assign contents of each wav file from filesList to a string     


try {


    for(File f : filesList){

        if(f.isFile()){

            AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(f.getName()));
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

            AudioInputStream appendedFiles = 
            new AudioInputStream(
                new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),     
                clip1.getFormat(), 
                clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

        AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                new File("output" + "(f.getName()).wav"));

        }
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

This compiles, but returns the following error on execution:-

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: glitch2.wav (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1181)
    at silapp_2b.main(silapp_2b.java:32)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that since you are iterating over the audio files, you don't have to create a new `File` object , you may simply replace `new File(f.getName())`  with `f` .

Comment: use `f.getAbsolutePath()` instead, try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error**

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(f.getName()));
```

This tries to create a file with the given file name, and looks for it in the current directory.

You should be using [File.getAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) to get the full absolute path to the file

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()));
```

or more simply

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
```

**Same problem with wavFile2**

I suspect you will have the same issue with the second file:

```
AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));
```

You will need to provide an absolute path here too. If it also is in the `audDir` then do

```
File wavFile2 = new File(audDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/silence_2sec.wav");
AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavFile2);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. getAbsolutePath brings in the the file form the audio directory - the other file (wavFile2)  is already in the program directory, so that works OK.  However, the for loop does not iterate through all the files in the directory, and I cannot seem to find a reason for that

Comment: @Diddlepara do you have nested directories? as you coded it it should go through all the files, but not go into directories

Comment: no - just one directory, named "audiofiles", placed in the program directory.  The idea being that I can place a number of files into that directory, run the short Java program, and it will output a series of audio files, each with the "silence_2sec.wav" file concatenated to it.

Comment: Are all the files in `filesList `, right after you build it? maybe the `if(f.isFile())` is filtering some files you want to keep for some reason. This might be a different question altogether. Please accept my answer if it solved your initial problem.

Comment: your answer certainly solved the initial query, and I will accept it. It appears that the for loop is a separate problem

Comment: @Diddlepara Thanks. I suggest you just right a new question, make sure you give the folders arborescence and a System.out after you create the file list.